# File checking code for F#

Tags: file, f#

I have this code to raise an error when file doesn't exist.

```
if !File.Exists(doFile) then
    printfn "doFile doesn't exist %s" doFile; failwith "quit"
```

However, I got this error. What's wrong?

```
error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    bool ref    
but here has type
    bool
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `!` operator has a special meaning in F#, its defined as:

```
type 'a ref { Contents : 'a }
let (!) (x : ref 'a) = x.Contents
```

You're getting the error because the `!` operator expects a `bool ref`, but you passed it a `bool`.

Use the `not` function instead:

```
if not(File.Exists(doFile)) then
    printfn "doFile doesn't exist %s" doFile; failwith "quit"
```

Answer (score 7):

in F# ! is not a NOT, it's a referencing operatior, so to say not, you need to use the not function, something like `if not <| File.Exists....`

Comment: A good example of where using backwards pipe makes things more readable.